# About The Lighting In Arda After The Destruction Of The Two Lamps

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

It is Known that Melkor (Morgoth) destroyed the Two Lamps, Ormal And Illuin. Meanwhile Valinor was lit by the Two Trees, and in Middle-earth the first light that Elves-Quendi beheld was that of the stars, when they awoke In Cuiviénen. My question is: what lit Arda during that, and before the Sun and Moon appeared? Only the Stars?

Comment: Special Thanks To Jimmy Shelter

Comment: We're improving your question to make it more useful and keep it from being closed. You shouldn't post copyrighted images online without attribution.

Comment: @user23291 - you still haven't read the [**Tour**](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) page.  If you did you'd understand why your questions are being edited.

Comment: @user23291: I disagree.  [This appears to be the image's source](http://www.elfwood.com/~jrpatch/Destruction-of-Illuin.3540889.html); the copyright clearly states (emphasis added) "©Jordan Ross Patchak. **All rights reserved!**", and there appear to be no CC-like allowances for reuse elsewhere.  I'm removing the picture.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing.

From the Silmarillion, chapter 1:

> But as the ages drew on to the hour appointed by Ilúvatar for the coming of the Firstborn, **Middle-earth lay in a twilight beneath the stars** that Varda had wrought in the ages forgotten of her labours in Eä.

Chapter 3:

> **Middle-earth lay in a twilight under the stars**. While the Lamps had shone, growth began there which now was checked, because **all was again dark**.

Also Chapter 3:

> Then Varda went forth from the council, and she looked out from the height of Taniquetil, and beheld **the darkness of Middle-earth beneath the innumerable stars**, faint and far.

And Chapter 11:

> These things the Valar did, recalling in their twilight **the darkness of the lands of Arda**; and they resolved now to illumine Middle-earth and with light to hinder the deeds of Melkor.

Comment: Great Answer :)

Comment: Strange...twilight is caused by the sun

Comment: As the world was still flat at that point, I would imagine an eternal twilight in the west from the 2 trees, calling to the elves to go to Valinor